# Does weak $H^1$ convergence imply $L^2$ convergence when multiplied with an exponentially decaying function?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, limits-and-convergence

I'm trying to see if given a sequence $\{f_n\}_n\in H^1$ which converges weakly in $H^1$ to a function $f_*$, the $L^2$ norm $\|R^2f_n\|_{L^2}^2$ converges to $\|R^2f_*\|^2_{L^2}$, where $R$ is a positive, exponentially decaying function.

My attempt is the following:
$$
\begin{split}
\int (R^4(f_n^2-f_*^2)) & \leq\int \big(R^4|f_n+f_*||f_n-f_*|\big)\\ &\leq\left(\int R^4|f_n+f_*|^2|f_n-f_*|\right)^{1/2}\left(\int R^4|f_n-f_*|\right)^{1/2}
\end{split}
$$
so the latter term goes to zero and it suffices that first integral is unif bounded, looks like that should be possible since $R$ is exponentially decaying?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't multiplication by $R^2$ a continuous linear operator on $L^2$ since $R$ will be bounded, and then the claim just follows from Rellich-Kondrachov?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Indeed, we have $R^2f_n\to R^2f_*$ in $L^2$. I take the integration domain to be $\mathbb R^d$, i.e., $L^2=L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ and $H^1=H^1(\mathbb R^d)$. We assume that $R(x)^2\leq Ce^{-\alpha\|x\|}$ for some $C>0$, $\alpha>0$ and for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$.

Since $f_n$ converges weakly in $H^1$, there exists $M>0$ such that $\sup_n\|f_n\|_{H^1}+\|f_*\|_{H^1}\leq M$, hence $\|f_n-f\|_{L^2}\leq 2M$ for all $n$. For any $r>0$, we denote $B_r:=\{x\in\mathbb R^d| \|x\|\leq r\}$. By the [Rellich–Kondrachov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem), the embedding $H^1(B_r)\hookrightarrow L^2(B_r)$ is compact for each $r>0$. Since compact operators are [completely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Completely_continuous_operators), we know that $f_n\to f_*$ in $L^2(B_r)$ for each $r>0$.

For an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, we choose $r>0$ be such that $(Ce^{-\alpha r})^2(2M)^2<\frac\epsilon2$; since $f_n\to f_*$ in $L^2(B_r)$ there exists $N$ such that
$$\int_{B_r}|f_n(x)-f_*(x)|^2\,dx< \frac\epsilon{2C^2}, \qquad \text{for }n>N.$$
Then for $n>N$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^d}|R^2f_n(x)-R^2f_*(x)|^2\,dx&=\int_{B_r}|R^2f_n(x)-R^2f_*(x)|^2\,dx+\int_{\mathbb R^d\setminus B_r}|R^2f_n(x)-R^2f_*(x)|^2\,dx\\
&\leq C^2\int_{B_r}|f_n(x)-f_*(x)|^2\,dx+(Ce^{-\alpha r})^2\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f_n(x)-f_*(x)|^2\,dx\\
&<\frac\epsilon2+(Ce^{-\alpha r})^2\|f_n-f_*\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2\leq\frac\epsilon2+(Ce^{-\alpha r})^2(2M)^2<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R^d}|R^2f_n(x)-R^2f_*(x)|^2\,dx=0,$$
thus $R^2f_n\to R^2f_*$ in $L^2$ and hence the $L^2$ norm $\|R^2f_n\|_{L^2}^2$ converges to $\|R^2f_*\|^2_{L^2}$.